# Updating Methods & Classes for Cocos2d 1.0.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have been working on porting this project over from the old version of cocos2d .99.4 to the new version, 1.0.1.

As you might imagine, the class names and methods have been renamed since then. I have been using this website:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/deprecated.html

to figure out which classes and filenames have replaced which, but I am still trying to figure out which classes:

`CCSpriteFrame (with the corresponding method 'initWithSpriteFrameName')
CCFadeTransition`

have been deprecated to, given that at least 7 versions of cocos2d have been released between the current and the engine I was working with.

edit: Figured out the initWithSpriteFrameName method; the correct method for 1.0.1 is `initWithFrames:frame delay:delay;`

and figured out that CCFadeTransition should be replaced with CCTransitionFade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in [my upgrade guide](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/) and here's the [list of changes that I had to implement](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/learn-cocos2d-book-source-code-update/) to upgrade my book's source code from cocos2d 0.99.3 to 0.99.5 to 1.0.1.